# Variance of first n binary digits of pi?

Tags: statistics, pi

I recently asked myself a question but didn't have the slightest inkling on how to solve it.

### Question

If we convert $\pi$ to a binary digit. We know the first $n$ digits the average number of $0$'s are the same as the average number of $1$'s. My question is what is the variance as a function of the first $n$ digits?

Comment: The leading diigt is of course known to be one.  If you wanted to make a simplifying assumption, the following binary expansion could be modelled as a [Bernoulli process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_process).  In reality the binary expansion is deterministic, but for a sample of $n$ with [Bernoulli distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) the variance is easily computed.

Comment: Actually, we don't know that; as far as I know that's an open problem. (Of course we conjecture it and it's almost certainly true.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Discrete_random_variable) gives us that the variance of a set of values is $\frac 1{n^2}\sum_i\sum_{j\gt i}(x_i-x_j)^2$.  If there are $k$ terms that are $1$ and $n-k$ terms that are $0$, this gives $\frac {k(n-k)}{n^2}$ If about half the digits are $1$ this gives $\frac 14$.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not totally convinced one can model $\pi$ as a Bernoulli process. Any reference or computation will be greatly appreciated?

Comment: We believe that $\pi$ is normal, which implies that on average half the bits will be $1$s (and much more).  That is all we need here.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a proof but a demonstration of what happens. The graph below shows the sample standard deviation and mean of the first $n$, inclusive, bits of $\pi$ in base $2$, for $1\leq n\leq 128$. The standard deviation of the bits up to $n$ appears to converge pretty quickly to $0.5$, which agrees with **Ross Millikan's** answer that the variance may converge to $\frac14=0.5^2$. The mean of the bits appears to converge to approximately $0.42$ but theoretically it would converge to $0.5$, if $\pi$ is normal.

[image: mean and stdev of binary pi]

The value of $\pi=11.001\ldots_{2}$ is from http://www.exploringbinary.com/pi-and-e-in-binary/ and the graph was made in GeoGebra 5.0.274.0-3D. The .ggb file is available from https://ufile.io/gp92i.